# YAML over XML for configuration files?

Tags: xml, configuration, yaml

Is there any compelling reason to select YAML over XML for configuration files?

YAML seems all the rage now on Github, but I'm just not seeing the advantage. I don't like having to worry about getting the whitespace right, and I've already got good XML editors and validators. And I can read XML just fine, even without my reading glasses.

So is it ok that I remain a crusty XML luddite? Or should I become a YAML hipster because everyone's doing it?

(BTW, JSON isn't an option because it doesn't support comments.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure json does allow comments...

Comment: Official JSON doesn't allow comments. That applies regardless which of the specs you regard as official. But many parsers are lax and will accept things that the specification doesn't allow.

Comment: I don't like either XML or YAML, but you obviously like XML so why are you trying to fix something that you don't perceive as being broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAML is less verbose and cheaper to parse than XML. It has fewer optional, generally unused features than XML. It presents a simpler data model, with no concept of mixed content.

> YAML seems all the rage now on Github

If this is the audience you're writing for then familiarity may be another benefit.

The nature of what you're configuring should play a large part in your decision. Will the configuration files need to be extensible, or to include existing XML languages? Will having XML's schema-aware editors help with complex cases?

> So is it ok that I remain a crusty XML luddite?

Of course; both have their strengths. And don't overlook property files, for even simpler cases.

Comment: I've changed my ways. I like yaml now.